# How can I match Base* against a list of Derived*, from within Base destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, derived-class, rtti

I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. I have a container which stores a list of `Derived*` pointers.

There is a signal/slot mechanism which emits a signal when a Base object is destroyed, and at that point we are inside `~Base` destructor, so RTTI is not available for converting `Base*` to `Derived*` (this is using Qt, but the question is not Qt specific)

That signal is connected to a slot managing the pointer container. As you may have guessed, I want to check if the `Base*` pointer whose object is being destroyed corresponds to a `Derived*` pointer stored inside the container, and if so, remove it from the container.

I know there are many alternative designs, such as not using the `QObject::destroyed()` signal, or storing a list of `QObject*` instead of `Derived*`. But I'd like to use that one for many practical reasons.

Which means, I want to convert a base pointer to a derived pointer, not for dereferencing, but for untracking the pointer, and I want it to be defined behavior whatever the subclassing tree is (including multiple inheritance, virtual functions...).

Can I use static_cast for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Oops - thanks for noticing

Comment: Well, you can use a `static_cast` but you have to be sure to have the correct type.

Comment: @DavidHaim : As I said, I know there are other possible designs but the question is specific here. I cannot modify the Base class here (which is the QObject Qt base class)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : could you explain ? The potential problems of static_cast are exactly what I'm missing.

Comment: @DavidHaim : Then I have to rewrite Qt. The base class, the signal slot mechanism, are all core features of the framework.

Comment: @galinette The potential problem is that you need to be sure that a `Base*` pointer points a `Derived` instance. The `static_cast<>` just check there's a relation between `Base` and `Derived` at compile time.

Comment: Based on the question text, your real question is "How do I cast `Base*` to `Derived*` in the Base destructor?

Comment: @M.M : Yes, but for a very restrictive use : comparing the cast pointer to a table Derived* pointers for removing it. Of course I will not dereference the cast pointer. Is there any chance to have defined behavior here?

Comment: You should mention whether `Base` has any virtual functions

Comment: Instead of each object knowing about the container it might be in, why not just let the object be automatically destroyed when it's no longer in a container? I.e. use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `static_cast` to the `base` type for each element of your container and compare it with your `*base ptr`. Thus you will find the object.

```
class Base;
class Derived;
std::vector<Derived*> arrDerived;

void Remove(Base* pBase);

class Base
{
public:
    ~Base()
    {
        Remove(this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{

};

void Remove(Base* pBase)
{
    for (Derived* pDerived : arrDerived)
    {
        //if (static_cast<Base*>(pDerived) == pBase) same as
        if (pDerived == pBase)
        {
            //you found it!!!!
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When you do `static_cast<Base*>(Derived)` compiler just moves `ptr` by some `const` amount of memory lower (so it points to the base class). Therefore this operation is independent on actual memory status and `safe` for you.

Edit: as @alain mentioned you can compare without `static_cast` - it will be performed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What are the cases where doing the opposite (upcasting the ptr) would be undefined behavior?

Comment: I've edited answer. Upcasting will work even if you destroy all objects :) The thing is what `upcasting` of `invalid pointer` will give `invalid pointer`. But for search it does not metter.

Answer (score 4):

In a comment, you wrote:

> comparing the cast pointer to a table Derived* pointers for removing
>   it. Of course I will not dereference the cast pointer.

In this case, no cast is needed at all, you can compare your pointers directly:

```
Base* base;
Derived* derived;
if(base == derived) {
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. `static_cast` performs automatically.